# unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Estoy generando una consulta en *Laravel*, pero tengo dos casos y en ves de hacer un *if* y colocar la consulta dos veces quise generar un *string* y concatenarlo a mi consulta pero me manda este error:

> syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Ya intente varios formas de concatenar el *string*. Mi pregunta es: ¿puedo en una consulta concatenar un *string* para evitar colocar esta consulta dos veces?.

```
if (session('empresa_id') == 0) {
            $filter_products = "";
        }else{
            $filter_products = "->where('products.products_price','<',2000)";
        }
        
        $products_salud = DB::table('products')
        ->join('products_to_categories', 'products.products_id', '=', 'products_to_categories.products_id')
        ->join('categories', 'categories.categories_id', '=', 'products_to_categories.categories_id')
        ->join('image_categories','image_categories.image_id','products.products_image')
        ->join('products_description','products_description.products_id','products.products_id')
        ->where('categories.categories_slug','=','salud')
        ->where('image_categories.image_type','=','MEDIUM')
        .$filter_products.
        ->select('products.*','products_to_categories.*','categories.*','image_categories.*','products_description.*')
        ->groupBy('products.products_id')
        ->limit(6)
        ->get();
```

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta y explicar que hace tu consulta o que datos quieres obtener, para así poder ayudarte a generar una mejor consulta :)

Comment: Lo que intentas es totalmente erróneo, debido a un error de sintaxis de PHP , y me atrevo a decir que de cualquier lenguaje de programación, puedes intentar esto `->where($column,$value)` y en tus variables solo algo como esto `$column = 'products.products_price'; $value = 2000;` pero de igual manera creo que no sera la mejor forma

Comment: El problema @Josbert es que ese where debe de desaparecer en el if. Y es lo que no le encuentro solución. Si no tendre que colocar la consulta dos veces :(

Comment: @Hugo dame unos minutos para plantearte una solución amigo ;)

Comment: Va que va, ya intente varias maneras y no mas no. Pienso que tal ves no se puede hacer lo que busco

Comment: Mientras tanto por favor explica un poco de que se trata este valor `(session('empresa_id')`, veo que tiene un **id** tal vez esto pueda ayudarnos un poco

Comment: Solo indica el id de las empresas. En realidad la consulta ya funciona. Solo busco optimizarla y ver si puedo quitar ese where sin hacer otra consulta

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿Por que no usas las relaciones de **Laravel** y te ahorras muchos `join`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes tratar de la siguiente forma:

- Asigna en una variable tu query inicial
- Posterior por medio del empleo de [*las claúsulas condicionales*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses) evaluar que valor tiene la clave `empresa_id`

  - Solo si la condición resulta cierta se ejecutará la query que esta dentro del *callback*
  - En caso contrario retornamos los valores que nos daría la consulta inicial

Query:

```
$consultaInicial = DB::table('users')
                ->join('products_to_categories', 'products.products_id', '=', 'products_to_categories.products_id')
                ->join('categories', 'categories.categories_id', '=', 'products_to_categories.categories_id')
                ->join('image_categories','image_categories.image_id','products.products_image')
                ->join('products_description','products_description.products_id','products.products_id')
                ->where('categories.categories_slug','=','salud')
                ->where('image_categories.image_type','=','MEDIUM')
                ->select('products.*','products_to_categories.*','categories.*','image_categories.*','products_description.*')
                ->groupBy('products.products_id')
                ->limit(6);

$consultaCondicionada = $consultaInicial->when(session('empresa_id') !== 0, function ($query) {

    return $query->where('products.products_price','<',2000);

})->get();

return $consultaCondicionada;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era lo que buscaba!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Continuando con la pequeña discusión en los comentarios, la solución que se me ocurre es; por lo que entiendo, quieres traer todos los productos en donde su valor sea menor a `2000` solo cuando `(session('empresa_id')` esta presente; de resto traer todos los productos existentes sin esta condición.

Puedes simplemente colocar un valor alto, por defecto a la consulta, un valor que exceda el precio posible de los productos, tal vez `4294967295`, que es el valor máximo soportado por las columnas de tipo `integer` en **MySQL**.

Algo así:

```php
$filter_products = 2000;

if (session('empresa_id') == 0) {
  $filter_products = 4294967295;
}
        
    $products_salud = DB::table('products')
    ->join('products_to_categories', 'products.products_id', '=', 'products_to_categories.products_id')
    ->join('categories', 'categories.categories_id', '=', 'products_to_categories.categories_id')
    ->join('image_categories','image_categories.image_id','products.products_image')
    ->join('products_description','products_description.products_id','products.products_id')
    ->where('categories.categories_slug','=','salud')
    ->where('image_categories.image_type','=','MEDIUM')
    ->where('products.products_price', '<', $filter_products)
    ->select('products.*','products_to_categories.*','categories.*','image_categories.*','products_description.*')
    ->groupBy('products.products_id')
    ->limit(6)
    ->get();
```

Espero haber entendido del todo lo que quieres hacer, en caso de que no desees traer ningún registro y yo este confundido puedes cambiar el `4294967295` por un `0` tal vez.

Te recomiendo encarecidamente que explores las [Relaciones de **Eloquent**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) y te ayudes con ellas, solucionara y optimizara mucho tus consultas.

Comment: Entiendo tu idea y es buena, deja lo intento